# ¿como sumar un arreglo con otro usando for?

Tags: java, array

como hago para la suma mede
5|11|12|15|7|2
y que no me quede a si
3 | 7 | 5 | 10 | 4 | 2 |
que debo modificar para que me dé el primer resultado

```
        int ar1[]= {2,6,4,9,3,1};
        int ar2[]= new int[]{3,5,8,6,4,1};
        
         int resultado[] = new int[6];
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<ar1.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<ar2.length; j++)
            {
            resultado[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[j];
        }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<resultado.length; i++)
        {
         System.out.print(resultado[i] + " | ");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Holaa, bueno probé tu código y lo solucione cambiando los 'for' que recorren los recorren cada uno, solo por uno que tenga los espacios de cada arreglo (6), ahora suma los numero correctamente

```
int arreglo1[]= {2,6,4,9,3,1};
int arreglo2[]= {3,5,8,6,4,1};
    
int resultado[] = new int[6];
    
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   resultado[i] = arreglo1[i] + arreglo2[i];
}
    
for(int i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){
   System.out.print(resultado[i] + " | ");
}
```